# Windows 8 Install Hanging at first white-font boot splash

Tags: usb, windows-8-preview, windows-8, uefi

I'm trying to install the Windows 8 preview on my Samsung Series 9 (2012, Ivy Bridge).

I've done a bit of a custom scheme with this one:

- I'm using EFI/UEFI on this system.
- I've seen no indication that this system supports secure boot (yay!)
- My SSD is set up with GPT
- Ubuntu is already installed and working **great** via UEFI.
- I'm trying to boot the Windows 8 install from a USB stick via UEFI
- I don't have access to a CD drive.

The problem is that the boot seems to hang at the very first splash screen that [looks like this](http://pureinfotech.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/new-windows-8-splash.png). White windows font, the little beads don't show up.

My USB stick has an activity light and it does blink for the first few seconds, but then goes back to it's "nobody is talking to me" idle pulse.

What I know:

- UEFI booting is definitely working.
- Windows 8 for those few seconds seems to have some kind of access to the USB drive.
- My Series 9 is running the latest BIOS/firmware.

Any idea what I might be able to do to get Windows 8 installed??

Comment: That splash screen you're showing is for the Release Preview. Did you try it on RTM?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this before when installing from bad provisions of the USB stick. It seems that some sticks just don't want to work (I couldn't get it to work with one stick, but trying again with another stick worked better)

Try it with a different USB stick, or reformat and try your stick again. Failing that, I know DVD burns always work.

This is a problem with the Microsoft provided USB creation tool having bugs. It is better in RTM version but still has occasional problems.

My fix? Burned the ISO on a DVD. Slower, but it works every time.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that your ISO is 100% correct. Try downloading a new ISO. Verify the checksum with `sha1sum`.

Confirm that your installation media is 100% correct. Try using a nonWindows program to burn the DVD; use Linux or Mac OS X (e.g. `Disk Utility`).